# Shift of finitely many reals into irrationals

Tags: real-numbers, irrational-numbers

This question came in one of class-room discussion.

> Given finitely many distinct real numbers $x_1,x_2,\cdots, x_n$, does there exists a real number $y$ such that $y+x_1, y+x_2, \cdots, y+x_n$ are irrational?

(Similar question can be posed with expectation that $y+x_i$ are *rational* for all $i$.)

Comment: Yes, because $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable. No for the second question.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to prove (I was in confusion, whether this is possible or not. Thanks for convening of truth.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT (if you are familiar with uncountable sets): For any $x$, how many $y$ are there such that $x+y$ is rational? How does this compare to the whole set of reals? Do you see how to bring multiple different $x$ into it?

Note, by the way, that this works even if we have *infinitely many* (but *countably many*) $x$.

You may also be interested in the **Baire category theorem**.

---

For the second question, the answer is no even for two values of $x$: do you see why $y+0$ and $y+\pi$ can never both be rational?

Comment: Great. Nice answer.